# How do I use CallNtPowerInformation (with Interop) to get Windows SystemExecutionState?

Tags: c#, interop, pinvoke

I'm really struggling with using the [CallNtPowerInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372675%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function in C#. I need to get the Windows SystemExecutionState. (Possible values [listed here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373208%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

I've found the appropriate C# signature:

```
    [DllImport("powrprof.dll", SetLastError = true)]

    private static extern UInt32 CallNtPowerInformation(
         Int32 InformationLevel,
         IntPtr lpInputBuffer,
         UInt32 nInputBufferSize,
         IntPtr lpOutputBuffer,
         UInt32 nOutputBufferSize
         );
```

Now I need to use information level 16 to read the "SystemExecutionState". Here's the code I have so far:

```
IntPtr status = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(ulong)));
UInt32 returnValue = CallNtPowerInformation(
    16, 
    (IntPtr)null, 
    0, 
    status, (
    UInt32)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(ulong)));
Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(status);
```

According to the Microsoft documentation:

> The lpOutputBuffer buffer receives a ULONG value containing the system
>   execution state buffer.

How do I get the ULONG value from the IntPtr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [`Marshal.ReadInt32(status)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eawzfdz5.aspx) to get the value.

```
uint statusValue = (uint)Marshal.ReadInt32(status);
```

The `Marshal` class has a whole family of `ReadXXX` methods that allow you to read from unmanaged memory.

Comment: This is working, thank you. Just trying to decide if I should use this method or SLaks's.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `out uint` instead of an `IntPtr`.

```
[DllImport("powrprof.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern UInt32 CallNtPowerInformation(
     Int32 InformationLevel,
     IntPtr lpInputBuffer,
     UInt32 nInputBufferSize,
     out uint lpOutputBuffer,
     UInt32 nOutputBufferSize
);


uint result;
CallNtPowerInformation(..., out result);
```

Comment: +1 This is certainly an option, but it does limit the use of `CallNtPowerInformation` to 32 bit sized-values. If you are only using  `CallNtPowerInformation` for this one value, `SystemExecutionState`, then I would do it this way. If you want to re-purpose the DllImport of `CallNtPowerInformation` then `Marshal.ReadInt32` and its friends, is the way to go.

Comment: Is there any other reason not to use Marshal?

Comment: @James You can really do it either way. Both work perfectly. It just comes down to which is more convenient for you.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: You could also make multiple overloads.

Comment: @Slaks Yes indeed. That can work quite well. Lots of options!!